# Best way to model a quota system for a subscription messaging service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a rails application that has a subscription aspect with three plan levels depending on price tier. For example, 0-1000 messages is $10, 1001-10000 is $20, and a $0.01 surcharge on both for going over the quota amount.

Each User has many Messages. What's the best way (high level) to keep track of each user's message usage and overages and charge them accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need these elements:

> 1. Way to track number of messages (caching)
> 2. Way to track payment system (how to calculate surcharges etc)
> 3. Scheduled process of charging

---

**Messages**

To track the sent messages, you need a caching system (calculating on the fly will be expensive). I don't have that much experience here, but I'd recommend looking at [Redis](http://redis.io) (you may wish to [research caching here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html))

I would use Redis to store a `key/value pair` for all the month's messages. So when a message is created in your DB, have a mechanism to add the update to a Redis hash (which will belong to a user ID)

> - [Instagram info on Redis](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs)
> - [Redis Hashes](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) (store message date per username)

The Redis key/values will be to store the message timestamp (`created_at`) & the `user_id` of the message. This means you'll be able to reference the month's Redis store & dump to another db (to reference later on), allowing you to calculate how many messages each user sent

---

**Payments**

To enable a tier-based pricing structure, you'll need to be able to calculate the monthly invoices to send out. This should be an internal system, basically creating a mechanism to present a user with an invoice, and sending them to a payment provider to transfer the funds

To calculate the invoice, you'll basically need to run a rake task to do this:

> 1. Cycle through the user's Redis store
> 2. Store the Redis store in a db (maybe)
> 3. Take a "count" of messages
> 4. Use simple algorithm to determine price
> 5. Create priced `invoice` & associated record in `invoice_messages` table (where you can itemise message usage)

---

**Scheduling**

Although a relatively small feature, you'll need to schedule your invoice creation

I'm actually thinking about this currently (not much experience), so to do this, you'll need to set up a rake task to cycle through when a user should be invoiced. Depending on your app, you'll have to determine the right invoice date & then run the previous steps depending on it

Comment: Thanks, rich! very helpful. i'm planning on using stripe's subscriptions feature as the payments, so there wouldn't be an invoice. maybe surcharges just aren't the best way to go.

Comment: No problem - hope you get somewhere with it! We've been building a marketing-type system which uses something similar. We're looking at prices per functionality

Comment: What about for overages? My plan is to wait for a successful charge of a user's card, reset the quota, and charge for any overages. is it good practice to wait for the successful charge of the monthly plan to check the quota?

Comment: No it's not good practice because the buyer will want to pay a single price. Imagine if your phone bill came out in 2 different transactions - it will be a mess. You're best calculating the net price to the buyer before presenting them with an invoice